# Параметризированный запрос SQL-Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, запрос, visual-studio, sql

Не работает параметризированный запрос к БД SQL-Server. Для текущего узла TreeView я вывожу данные из связанной таблицы

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        string cur = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TestBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        string commandText = "SELECT Employees.Name, Employees.Experience FROM Departments INNER JOIN Employees ON Departments.id=Employees.Department WHERE Departments.Name=" + cur + ";";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandText, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
```

Если в запросе убираю WHERE, то все работает, но выводятся все записи, а мне надо лишь определенные.
На строке dataAdapter.Fill(ds) вылетает исключение SQLException: Invalid column name 'Бухгалтерия'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно делать через параметры и через SqlCommand:

```
string commandText = "SELECT Employees.Name, Employees.Experience FROM Departments INNER JOIN Employees ON Departments.id=Employees.Department WHERE Departments.Name=@Name;";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn); 
SqlParameter Param1 = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Param1.Value = cur;
cmd.Parameters.Add(Param1);

SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Comment: Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.SqlDataAdapter(string, string)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов

Не нравится ему последняя строчка, хотя есть метод с данными параметрыми

Comment: да, второй параметр лишний, достаточно cmd.

Comment: Кстати, результат все равно тот же самый

Comment: у меня к сожалению нет возможности проверить, но это верный путь. указывать значения параметров в строке запроса - порочная практика.

Comment: Ошибка: Fill: Свойство SelectCommand.Connection не инициализировано.

Comment: Решил проблему, добавив
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText,conn);

Comment: @Павел Воевода, получилось? Смысл в том, что указание какого-либо значения в теле запроса, кроме int'ов, может быть искажено по пути из кода в драйвер в субд. Поэтому стоит всегда пользоваться параметрами. Во-первых, вы имеете возможность использовать один и тот же запрос для разных значений параметра (просто меняя его значение), во-вторых, гарантируете передачу верного значения в запрос (кодировки, длины и т.д.).  

ЗЫ поправил ответ, для comm добавил conn в конструктор.

Answer (score -1):

Если Departments.Name - строковый, то надо поставить "'". Т.е. `...Departments.Name='" + cur + "';"`. Но все-же лучше, как советовал Yura Ivanov. К примеру, дату проще задавать через параметры.