# Параметризованный запрос в C#

Tags: c#

Моя цель - создать запрос, который будет выбирать записи из БД, которые соответствуют определённой переменной "kod". Вот что я пишу:

```
 MyQuery = "Select Часов, КодПреподавателя From Нагрузка Where КодПреподавателя = '"kod"' ";
```

Но последние двойные кавычки считаются компилятором отдельно, из-за чего возникает ошибка. Проверил достаточно способов, пока ни один не подошёл. Как мне исправить эту запись, чтобы она выполняла свою цель?

Comment: Это можно нагуглить за одну минуту, если гуглить по запросу "Параметризованные запросы в C#,  T-SQL" - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/236202/185863

Comment: попробуйте вот так: `MyQuery = $"Select Часов, КодПреподавателя From Нагрузка Where КодПреподавателя = '{kod}' ";`