# Реализовать поиск по дате c# Windows Forms (NET. Framework) + MSSQL

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server

возникла необходимость написать код, который будет выполнятся по нажатию на кнопку в форме по поиску записей из таблицы **Table_Vilety**, где главным параметром по поиску будет столбец **Time_vilet** (дата вылета для рейса (*datetime*)) из БД **Airport** на С# в *Windows Forms NET. Framework* с подключенной БД из *MSSQL Server*.

Фото формы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, написанный при помощи гайдов в интернете не дал результата:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-3SB9FF6\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Airport;Integrated Security=True");

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table_Vilety where Time_vilet = '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
```

***dateTimePicker1*** имеет формат "yyyy-MM-dd"
С таким же кодом работает поиск по ID или рейсу, но с типом данных как datetime вообще не получается. Буду рад, если подробно опишите, как в этом случае написать код.

P.S.: ***DataGridView1*** берет сам данные из таблицы (в коде нету внесения данных для каждого отдельного столбца. Работает и так, да и я не вижу смысла для огромной БД для каждой формы расписывать большой код).

Comment: Если у вас возникает проблема с тем, что БД не отдаёт вам нужные данные по запросу, стоит убедится в том, корректно ли вы форматируете дату для запроса. Отформатируйте дату и уже её вставляйте в sql-запрос. Ссылка на подобный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418258/datetime-format-to-sql-format-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Frehzy - щас забаню за плохой совет! (не забаню, я не модер)

Comment: Вызов `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` не имеет смысла, уберите его

Comment: Абсолютно буду согласен, если настучите по голове за такой ответ. Даже как-то не обратил внимание на то, что нет параметризации запроса. Пытаюсь исправиться - https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.9.php https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236199/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-sql-server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я прочёл все об этой теме тут: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418258/datetime-format-to-sql-format-using-c-sharp*

Спасибо Frehzy!

Ответ для себя я нашел достаточно простой. Нужно лишь дописать ***DateTime.Parse()*** чтобы преобразовать указанное строковое представление даты и времени в эквивалент DateTime, используя указанный формат и информацию о формате для конкретной культуры. Формат строкового представления должен точно соответствовать указанному формату "*yyyy-MM-dd*"

Полный запрос будет выглядеть следующим образом (надеюсь, что я смог помочь и другим, кто столкнется с этим вопросом):

***cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table_Vilety where Time_vilet = '" + DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text) + "'";***

Подробнее о самом преобразовании строки в другой формат тут:
*https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-6.0*

Прилагаю ссылку от Frehzy на полезный источник про парсинг в C# тут: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp*

Comment: Да, такой вариант тоже является приемлемым. По сути, и тот, и тот - конвертирует строку в нужный формат datetime. Можете добавить ссылку на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp

Comment: Тем не менее, хотелось-бы чуть исправить - пользуйтесь не свойством Text, а Value. Информация об этом https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711358/datetime-picker-c-sharp-format. Либо, можно заранее форматировать (CustomFormat). Об этом так же написано в посте выше

Comment: Минус мой. / Используйте параметризованный sql-запрос.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за источники. Это очень интересная и главное полезная тема таким новичкам как я

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю максимально упростить код следующим образом:

Строка соединения хранится в поле класса. По идее, она должна считываться из конфига.

```
private string _connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-3SB9FF6\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Airport;Integrated Security=True";
```

`SqlDataAdapter` может сам создать соединение, открыть и закрыть его, создать `SqlCommand`.

```
string sql = "select * from Table_Vilety where Time_vilet = @dt";

using var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, _connectionString);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("dt", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;


DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Обязательно используйте параметризованные sql-запросы! Это и от ошибок защитит, и производительность повысит.

Укажите правильный тип `SqlDbType` - я не знаю, какой именно тип у вас в БД. Надеюсь, там не (n)varchar...